# Including 3rd Party libraries in R project

Tags: c++, r, static-libraries, rstudio, rcpp

I'm attempting to include the qpOASES c++ library with an Rcpp project I'm building in RStudio.

I've looked through the Writing R Packages and various Rcpp vignettes. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570526/how-to-build-a-r-package-which-use-rcpp-with-external-c-libraries) which references [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/6004) archived conversation. Using that as I guide, I compiled the qpOASES library into a static (libqpOASES.a and libqpOASES.so) library. I followed this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gEDAGv0j48) on how to use an external library in RStudio. The video instructed me to create lib and inc folders inside my R project. Inside of the lib folder, the two static library files (libqpOASES.a & libqpOASES.so). Inside the inc folder, I have placed I have placed libqpOASES.hpp and a directory qpOASES which contains other header files referenced by libqpOASES.hpp).

I'm working on a windows pc, but the the package I create will ultimately need to work unix as well. Presently in my MakeVars (and Makevars.win) file, I have the following:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inc
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) -L../lib  -llibqpOASES
```

When I clean and rebuild the project: it builds successfully until the following:

```
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o default.dll tmp.def LS_LocalLaplacian.o RcppExports.o    RegularizedLeastSquares.o TrainNetworks.o affinityMatrix.o dist2.o dn.o dominateSet.o rcpparma_hello_world.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -L../lib -llibqpOASES -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
c:/rbuildtools/3.1/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibqpOASES
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'default'
```

I've checked the naming of things for typos, etc but haven't found the issue there. I tried removing "-llibqpOASES " from PKG_LIBS declaration, it compiles; however, when I attempt to use methods  provided by the qpOASES library, they cannot be found:

```
undefined reference to qpOASES::QProblem::QProblem(int, int, qpOASES::HessianType)'
RegularizedLeastSquares.o:RegularizedLeastSquares.cpp:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to
qpOASES::QProblem::~QProblem()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'default'
```

How do I successfully use an external C++ library in RStudio?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of existing packages which do this -- I would take one of those and see how it works.

A relatively recent example is [nloptr](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=nloptr) which binds to [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt).  I helped with making the Unix side of the build a little more flexible (ie either use the library if present, else download and build it -- before it always did the latter).  You could use this as a self-contained test case to compare too.

Comment: Just of note, the link to [nloptr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/nloptr/index.html) is corrected.  @dirk-eddelbuettel link just needed the `r` in `nloptr`